# GNU Linux (ext4 and others) how to find largest duplicate files?

Tags: linux, storage, ext4

Luckily there are [tools to find duplicate files](https://dwaves.de/2015/07/17/gnu-linux-how-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-files/), but unaware of any that output a sortable (by filesize) list.

How to find the top 30 duplicates sorted by filesize?

Have to sort out the msort X-D

```
fdupes -Sr . | grep "bytes each" -A 2 | sed "s/--/\n/g"
```

P.S. Spend quiet some time [compiling msort from src](https://dwaves.de/2023/10/04/gnu-linux-debian-how-to-build-bill-posers-and-bsds-msort-from-src/) (there are 2x versions with msort.utf8proc still not working)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the tool fdupes.

```
fdupes -Sr /tmp/
```

**Output:**

```
5 bytes each:                           
/tmp/file1
/tmp/file2
```

Explanation: https://linux.die.net/man/1/fdupes

- `-S` shows the size of duplicate files
- `-r` include files in subdirectories

Comment: thanks PacmanPenguin!

that is a start: but have to sort out the msort X-D

fdupes -Sr . | grep "bytes each" -A 2 | sed "s/--/\n/g"

Answer (score 0):

the solution: https://dwaves.de/2023/10/04/gnu-linux-debian-how-to-multi-line-sorting-madness-mlsm-how-to-output-x-blocks-of-text-separated-by-delimiter-build-bill-posers-and-bsds-msort-from-src/ (follow instructions there to install `czkawka_cli`, so good that there are still dedicated bloggers :D)

```sh
czkawka_cli dup --directories /where/to/search/for/duplicates/ | less
```

AUTOMATICALLY sorts by filesize

## in order to limit output to 30 blocks

```sh
czkawka_cli dup --directories /where/to/search/for/duplicates/ > /scripts/find_largest_30_duplicates.sh.txt

# then define this script

vim /scripts/output_x_amount_of_textblocks.sh 

#!/bin/bash
echo "=== output $2 amount of text blocks from $1 defined by delimiter $3 ==="
TEMPFILE=$1
# TEMPFILE=/scripts/find_largest_30_duplicates.sh.txt
# fdupes -Sr $1 | grep "bytes each" -A 2 > $TEMPFILE

BLOCK_LIMIT=$2
BLOCK_COUNTER=0
DELIMITER="$3"

while read -r LINE; do
    if [ $BLOCK_COUNTER -le $BLOCK_LIMIT ]; then
        # verbose output
        # echo "currently on block: "$BLOCK_COUNTER;

                echo "$LINE"

        if [[ "$LINE" == *"$DELIMITER"* ]]; then
            ((BLOCK_COUNTER++))
        fi
    fi
done < "$TEMPFILE"


# then call it like this
/scripts/output_x_amount_of_textblocks.sh "/scripts/find_largest_30_duplicates.sh.txt" 30 "----"
```

alternative with fdupes

```sh
# define script
vim /scripts/find_largest_30_duplicates.sh

#!/bin/bash
TEMPFILE=/scripts/find_largest_30_duplicates.sh.txt
fdupes -Sr $1 | grep "bytes each" -A 2 > $TEMPFILE

BLOCK_LIMIT=30
BLOCK_COUNTER=0
DELIMITER="--"

while read -r LINE; do
    if [ $BLOCK_COUNTER -le $BLOCK_LIMIT ]; then
        # verbose output
        # echo "currently on block: "$BLOCK_COUNTER;

                echo "$LINE"

        if [[ "$LINE" == *"$DELIMITER"* ]]; then
            ((BLOCK_COUNTER++))
        fi
    fi
done < "$TEMPFILE"


# call it like this
/scripts/find_largest_30_duplicates.sh "/where/to/search/for/duplicates/"
```